# $P(A \mid B) \leq P(A)$ if and only if $P(A \mid \overline{B}) \geq P(A)$

Tags: probability, inequality, conditional-probability

I am reading a paper that claims (without proof)

$$P(A \mid B) \leq P(A)$$
if and only if
$$P(A \mid \overline{B}) \geq P(A)$$

for any two events $A$ and $B$.

This seems reasonable, but I can't seem to prove it directly from the definition of conditional probability. Perhaps there is some identity involving these terms that I'm forgetting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $P(A)=P(B)P(A|B) + P(\bar B)P(A|\bar B)$.

Comment: I apologize for being dense. If I assume $P(A \mid B) \leq P(A)$, I derive only that $P(A \mid B) \leq P(A \mid \overline{B})$ using your hint.

Comment: In general, if $0\leq t\leq 1$ then $tX+(1-t)Y$ is between $X$ and $Y$. Let $t=P(B)$. Then $1-t=P(\bar B)$.

Comment: Essentially, what the above equation says is that $P(A)$ is a "weighted average" of $P(A|B)$ and $P(A|\bar B)$, and hence must be between these two values.

Comment: That's a very nice way to think of it. Thank you.